# CouchDB crashes on Windows 2008 R2 Standard with os_mon error

Tags: windows, crash, erlang, couchdb, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install CouchDB on a Windows 2008 R2 standard version server and it starts the couchdb service running but I am unable to access the couchdb url. And below is the error:

```
Erlang R15B (erts—5.9) [source] [smp:16:16] [async—threads:0]

Eshell V5.9 (abort with ^G)
1} ("init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,(error,{{app_would_not_start,os_mon
}, couch_app.start,[normal,["../etc/couchdb/default.ini","../etc/couchdb/local.i
ni"]]}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch.erl"},{line
,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{1ine,1041}]},{init,start_em,1,[{fi1e
,"init.erl"},{line.1022}]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: er]_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot {}

Abnormal termination
```

When tried on Windows 7 the same installer works fine. Please help on how to fix the issue as it has to run on the Windows 2008 R2 Standard server machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is if CouchDB starts from a command prompt, without running the service. The installer leaves an icon on the start menu for this, or you can try c:\couchdb\bin\couchdb.bat as well. I recommend installing to a filename without spaces just to ensure Windows is happy.

BTW you don't say what version/release of CouchDB this is, nor where you got it; R15B is not included in the recent official builds. I'd recommend the latest official release from http://couchdb.apache.org/#downloads which uses R16B02 and seeing how you get on.

Comment: I checked from the command prompt without running the service and it fails with the same reason. The couchdb version I am using is 1.2.0_otp_R15B. I'll try installing to a filename without spaces and check.

Comment: Thanks dch. The issue was with the spaces in the installation path